# (VBA) dynamic use of embedded excel functions

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, formula

I am tryin to postprocess data. As well I got column which have hour minute and second. With VBA I created a loop to go through every single row in a for loop.

```
For i = 2 To Max
Range("GE" & CStr(i + Offset)).Formula = "=TIME(AK & CStr(i + Offset);AL & CStr(i + Offset);AM & CStr(i + Offset))"
Next i
```

It comes to Run-time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error.

How can we edit this to be working?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: David 'mArm' Ansermot edited this. ehm it did not work, and i cant get the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i = 2 To Max
    Range("GE" & CStr(i + Offset)).Formula = "=TIME(AK" & CStr(i + Offset) & ",AL" & CStr(i + Offset) & ",AM" & CStr(i + Offset) & ")"
Next i
```

The loop variable needs to be "outside" the string you're entering as a formula to allow it to be built correctly.

This fixes the typo in your code, but you should consider setting the range specifically for the worksheet.

I've also changed your semicolons to commas as that's how the TIME function works in Excel here, but if your settings are different you might need to revert that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine. Did try that as well before but somehow got confused by all the ". However, what do u mean by "...setting the range specifically for the worksheet. "?

Comment: Your code is selecting the range for the active worksheet by default since you have not specified one; Suppose you want this to run against sheet1; should you have Sheet2 selected at the time you run the code, it will run against that sheet instead.  That can be avoided by declaring a variable as a worksheet and prefixing it to the Range (`Dim ws As Worksheet : Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheetnamehere")` and then referring to `ws.Range` rather than just `Range`

Comment: ah okay. Yeah i did this, the code was just a snippet and reduced to my problem. But Thank you again ;)